# Upload csv file to select columns in table

Tags: php, mysql, csv, load, import-from-csv

I have CSV file which has 3 columns, and my table has 4 columns(one of it is a id autoincrement which I want to be autoincremented). I want to load the 3 columns from csv to the selected 3 columns in the table.

Tried code:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'info.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_countryip (ipstart, ipend, countrycode) FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'  ;
```

which throws error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

Follow below steps-

1) connect with any gui like sqlyog.

2) select db > select table > right click on table > choose import > import csv data using load...

3) select all columns except primary key.

4) put 1 in ingnore line option if your csv file contains header.

5) click on import

If you want to do by command then command should be as per below-

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'info.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_countryip FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (ipstart, ipend, countrycode);
```

Note: If your corrent dir not where csv file exist then you need to give full path.

**If your csv file contains header line then you need to exclude it as per below-**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'info.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_countryip FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (ipstart, ipend, countrycode);
```

Comment: This is another way, he needs to do it via query.

Answer (score 2):

The list of columns is in the wrong place in your statement.  Follow the syntax in the documentation.

You want something like this:

```
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'info.csv' 
  INTO TABLE tbl_countryip 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  (ipstart, ipend, countrycode)
```

Reference:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

I removed the id column from the table, so both table and csv file had 3 columns, and then ran the load csv command, and then inserted a id column into the table with autoincrement.